# inputting & displaying of values

Tags: c++, input, vector

Below are the list of my codes. Please kindly take a look.
Option 1 is inputting of values. Whereas Option 5 is displaying of values.
The problem with my program is.

I dont have a problem inputting and displaying 1 set of values, it displays normally.
When i input 2 set of values for example like..

> (1, 1, Type O, 1, 1, 1, 1) <-- 1st set. (2, 2, Type K, 2, 2, 2, 2) <--
>   2nd set.

it displays like

> FIRST DISPLAY (2, 2, Type K, 2, 2, 2, 2) & 2ND DISPLAY (2,2,
>   BLANK,0,0,0,0).

Why is that so?
Thanks in advance to all who helps.

```
//DECLARATIONS
MissionPlan m;
int i;
PointTwoD pArray[2];
vector<PointTwoD> point2DVector = vector<PointTwoD> (); // instantiate an empty vector
vector<PointTwoD>::iterator point2DVectorIterator;
PointTwoD point2D;
LocationData locData;
int travdistance = 0;
int OptionChosen;

//OPTION CHOSEN
if (OptionChosen == 1)
{
    //declarations
    int i=0;
    int x, y, earth, moon;
    float Particulate, Plasma, civIndex;
    string sType;
    string mystr;

    cout<<"[Input Statistical data] \n";

    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Please enter x-ordinate: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> x;

    cout<<"Please enter y-ordinate: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> y;

    //cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Please enter sun type: ";
    getline (cin,sType);

    cout<<"Please enter no. of earth-like planets: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> earth;

    cout<<"Please enter no. of earth-like moons: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> moon;

    cout<<"Please enter ave. particulate density (%-tage): ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> Particulate;

    cout<<"Please enter ave. plasma density (%-tage): ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> Plasma;

    PointTwoD point2D = PointTwoD(x,y,locData, civIndex=0);
    point2DVector.push_back(point2D); // Insert newly formed point2D object to insert into the vector of PointTwoD objects
    point2DVector[i].setxCOORD(x);
    point2DVector[i].setyCOORD(y);
    point2DVector[i].locData.setSunType(sType);
    point2DVector[i].locData.setNoOfEarth(earth);
    point2DVector[i].locData.setNoOfMoon(moon);
    point2DVector[i].locData.setPartDensity(Particulate);
    point2DVector[i].locData.setPlasDensity(Plasma);
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Record successfully stored. Going back to the main menu ... \n";
    i++;
}


if (OptionChosen == 5)
{
    for(int i=0; i< point2DVector.size();i++)
    {
        cout << "************************************************ \n";
        cout << "            DISPLAY INPUT RECORDS                \n";
        cout << "************************************************ \n";
        cout << "x-ordinate:                " << point2DVector[i].getxCOORD() << "\n";
        cout << "y-ordinate:                " << point2DVector[i].getyCOORD() << "\n";
        cout << "sun type:              " << point2DVector[i].locData.getSunType() << "\n";
        cout << "no. of earth-like planets:     " << point2DVector[i].locData.getNoOfEarth() << "\n";
        cout << "no. of earth-like moons:       " << point2DVector[i].locData.getNoOfMoon() << "\n";
        cout << "ave. particulate density:      " << point2DVector[i].locData.getPartDensity() << "%" "\n";
        cout << "ave. plasma density:           " << point2DVector[i].locData.getPlasDensity() << "%" "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
if (OptionChosen == 1)
{
  //declarations
  int i=0;
```

You are resetting `i` to zero every time you select option 1.

You will be better off fully constructing `point2d` before adding to the `point2dVector` collection:

```
PointTwoD point2D = PointTwoD(x,y,locData, civIndex=0);
point2D.setxCOORD(x);
point2D.setyCOORD(y);
point2D.locData.setSunType(sType);
point2D.locData.setNoOfEarth(earth);
point2D.locData.setNoOfMoon(moon);
point2D.locData.setPartDensity(Particulate);
point2D.locData.setPlasDensity(Plasma);
point2DVector.push_back(point2D); // Insert newly formed point2D object to insert into
```

And then you can remove the `i` variable. This does mean that you need to make sure the copy constructor is correctly defined.

As an aside, spend some time learning how to use a debugger. That would have helped you find and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not reset i to 0 every time...